# How to delete files from Google Cloud Storage in a batch? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to delete 2 files, which depends themselves, from the gc storage at the "same time", in a batch. Until now I have been doing something like this:

```
exports.deleteImageFromBucket = async function (uri, bucket) {
  const imagePath = getStoragePathFromUrl(uri);

  try {
    await bucket.file(imagePath).delete();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error deleting image ${uri} from storage`);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

But, as I have images and their respective thumbnails, if I call this function two times and one of them rejects, this will cause a bad user experience.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the bad user experience you're concerned about?

Comment: Here you delete only one image? What's the problem to call 2 times this function on 2 different URIs (image and thumbnail)?

Comment: @DougStevensone in the client side I have images components which firstly load the thumbnail and then the hq image. In my algorithm, I firstly delete those two images, and then remove the associated documents in the db. If one of the two images fails when removing it, then my code will not touch the db and throw an error to the client, saying something like "Try again later", just to ensure that the storage is fully recycled (if the user tries it again later, then the two deletions might go fine, and there will no be any king of unnecessary garbage in the storage)...

Comment: ... but without a batched operation, if the thumbnail is not deleted, but the hq image yes, then the user will see the thumbnail in the image and will not be able to get the full quality one (it is an image with a progressive loading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no batch delete functionality for Cloud Storage that I know of. This means you'll have to:

1. Perform two individual delete calls.
2. Ensure any code loading images is robust enough to handle the absence of only one of these images. You can typically reduce the impact of this by deleting the images in a certain order. For example: if the user reaches a full-size image from the thumbnail, then deleting the thumbnail first ensures that the app will still work even when the full-size image remains behind.
3. Run a periodic process to remove orphaned file.